# What are the costs of a condition variable?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, pthreads, condition-variable

Assume that unused execution resources are available on the machine in question, i.e. not all CPUs are being utilized.  If a thread is waiting on a condition variable, what are the costs associated with waking up this thread?  Similarly, what are the costs associated with waiting on a condition variable?  I'm interested in both a rough quantification and where the costs come from.  To the extent that the answer is "it depends", I primarily care about recent versions of Windows and Linux on x86/x64.

Edit:  Since kernel calls are involved, how much more expensive is a kernel call than a regular function call?

Comment: @Tim:  I'm actually interested in D's core.sync.condition primitive but I left that out since I doubt many people around here are familiar with it.

Comment: Ah, I removed my question because I saw that you added a pthreads tag.  Is that because `core.sync.condition` is implemented with pthreads?

Comment: @Tim:  On Linux, I'm pretty sure it is.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any details about the pthreads or D implementations, but in general terms, the best-case overhead for a condition variable is one extra kernel call and possible context switch.

A typical implementation is just a wrapper around events and mutexes, and so the overhead and timings can be characterized by the behavior of those kernel objects.  On waiting the thread gives up the remainder of its scheduled time quantum and on waking up the thread gets scheduled by the kernel and gets the next available time quantum, based on its priority.  This depends heavily on load and kernel configuration, but will typically be within a few milliseconds.

For a condition variable, there's then the additional task of re-acquiring the mutex, which of course could block.  If it doesn't block, then it's still a kernel call.  This may end up being optimized down to a few atomic CPU instructions which are very fast by comparison, but are limited to a single process.  [ed: a CRITICAL_SECTION in Win32 or a futex in Linux, for example.]

The worst case is that the condition variable is spuriously triggered and the thread wakes up only to find that there's nothing to do, but that typically accounts for a negligible fraction of the total overhead.

Comment: Linux, just like Windows, also supports fast userspace mutexes. The kernel is involved only when blocking.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to your question although I don't think it is the answer you are looking for.

We benchmarked signals vs mutex/conditons to see which method could sleep and wake a thread faster.  For the signals, we used sigwait() to suspend and pthread_kill to wake.  For the mutex/conditions We used one mutex and one condition for each thread.  We found that we could sleep and wake threads 5x faster using signals.

We did not test futexes.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your final question:

> Since kernel calls are involved, how much more expensive is a kernel call than a regular function call?

Yes, roughly 1000 times more expensive.